# Unable to update Metal Gear Online

Tags: ps3, metal-gear-solid-4-guns-of-patriots

I am an absolutely massive Metal Gear Solid fan, and naturally own the 4th edition of the series - Guns of the Patriots. I found out there was online to it, and got very excited, until I realized I had to patch it. The HTTP download of the online patch does not start downloading after several minutes, and the P2P option is incredibly slow, with rates around 0.1kb/s. Is there any other way to patch the game? Is the online even up still? Konami is reporting to be be online, but it doesn't seem to be.

The Metal Gear Online website has proved useless for information on this topic, or any support.

Comment: Worth noting that the online no longer exists and was removed from the game.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out that the P2P download is slow and inefficient with few players seeding. I resorted to the HTTP download, and finally patched the game via an Ethernet connection. It was still very slow, but it finally downloaded after an extensive amount of time. There appears to be approximately 1000 players online still.